# PostgreSQL - Pattern Match - String to Sub-string

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching

I am trying to join two tables within a database, based upon a matching postcode, but am struggling where there are multiple postcodes relating to a single row of data.

i.e. **table 1** has 2 columns (a **unique ID** and **postcodes**). It is possible for a record to have just a single postcode in this column or multiple postcodes in comma-separated form.

**table 2** also has two columns (**development description** and **postcode**). In this table the postcode column can have only one postcode.

I would like to identify & join where the postcode from table 2 matches or is included within the relevant column in table 1. I have been able to do so where there is a single postcode within each column, but am currently unable to do so where there are multiple postcodes in table 1.

The below code brings back the matches where there is a single postcode.

```
SELECT      t1.id,
            t1.postcodes,
            t2.dev_description,
            t2.postcode
FROM        table1      AS  t1
INNER JOIN  table2  AS  t2
ON          t2.postcode LIKE    t1.postcodes
WHERE       t2.postcode =   'XXX XXX'
```

I have tried using `'%'|| ||'%'` and various other functions, but am at a bit of a loss to be honest.

If someone could help it would be great!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join on:

```
',' || t1.postcodes || ',' like  '%,' || t2.postcode || ',%'
```

This would expand to:

```
',1234AB,2345AB,3456AB,' like '%,1234AB,%'
```

Or you can use [`string_to_array`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) and the `@>` contains operator:

```
string_to_array(t1.postcodes, ',') @> array[t2.postcode]
```

This expands to:

```
array['1234AB','2345AB','3456AB'] @> array['1234AB']
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I've never joined two tables using ON and LIKE... Anyway, look up the command STRPOS.

Something like this perhaps:
...
OR (STRPOS(t1.postcodes, t2.postcode) > 0)
...